# WordPress and MS Exchange

Tags: email, exchange, wordpress

I have WordPress built on a RHEL VM for an intranet site with no outside access.

I'm being asked whether I can connect WordPress to the MS Exchange network so that I don't have to setup an email server when a new user registers.

I've looked into setting up an email server (looks like sendmail is default and postfix is a good alternative) but both require extensive time to setup and learn.

Is it possible to route the WordPress registration confirmation emails to the MS Exchange server somehow?